# How do I get inline tags to wrap nicely?

Tags: 7, theming

Inline tags are presented as a series of `<div>`s, with no whitespace in the HTML between them. These elements are styled `display:inline`, the result of which is an unbreakable string. When you have enough tags this breaks layout. What you want is tags to word-wrap around, but they don't.

The only way I can see to achieve this is by hacking core to insert a space after the field-item items' `<div>`s (or after the content before the closing `</div>`.

Is there another way? Perhaps a way for a theme to override the formatter function?

Comment: Are you saying that when you have enough tags, rather than the tags moving to the next line they just all stay on the same line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `display: inline-block` instead. It gives you the functionality of an inline element, but you can apply margins and padding to it just like a block-level element.

Comment: Ah I see. Does `float:left;` on those elements help at all?

Comment: ooh, you're quick! I deleted that comment while I did further testing! (for other readers, I *had* commented: Thanks, but this is far from simple. Because you have `div.field-label` then, `div.field-items` which contains the set of `div.field-item`s if you set `display:inline-block` on any of these the **label** is no longer inline.). Answer seems to be: set `inline` on the `.field-items` container and `inline-block` on the `.field-item` containers. I suspect `float:left` will be required by ie, not tested yet.

Comment: Ah yes, good old IE. Just hearing those two letters makes me want to tear my hair out! ;)

Answer (score 2):

I typically either make them `inline-block` or make my own [`theme_field`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.module/function/theme_field/7) for my theme.  I would say I tend to do the latter more.  Typically, I just copy the default implementation into my theme, rename, and make minor adjustments.  More often than not, though, I am already making formatters for specific fields.